# Undefined Variable Error in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel

I am a bit of a newbie to both PHP and Laravel and I trying to build simple Web Apps in order to familiarize myself with both PHP and Laravel. I am getting an `undefined variable` in blade file. It would be appreciated if someone could help me clear this up.

Basically, what I want to happen is:
I have a View called `dashboard.blade.php` and in this view there is a text field and button. When the room number is entered and the button is clicked, the room number must get saved in the database and the current view needs to get refreshed but this time, the new room has to be shown at the top. The room gets saved in the database without a problem, but when I try to retrieve it using the `foreach` loop, I get the **'undefined variable rooms'** error

I am using Laravel 5.2

The button concerned with firing off this action (in dashboard.blade.php)

```
<form action="{{ route('viewroom') }}" method="POST"> //route is viewroom
        Please Insert The New Room Number<br>
        <input type="text" name="roomid"/>
        <button type="submit">Add New Room</button>
        <input type="hidden" value="{{ Session::token() }}" name="_token"/>
</form>
```

Route file

```
Route::post('/dashboard',[
    'uses' => 'RoomController@InsertRoom',
    'as' => 'viewroom'
]);
```

Function used in the RoomController

```
public function InsertRoom(Request $request){
    $this->validate($request, [
        'roomid' => 'required | numeric | unique:insert_rooms',
    ]);

    $room = new InsertRoom();
    $room->roomid = $request['roomid'];
    $room->status = 0;
    $room->save();

    $rooms = InsertRoom::all();

    $request->session()->flash('alert-success', 'Room was successful added!');
    return view('dashboard', ['rooms' => $rooms]);
}
```

In dashboard.blade.php:

```
<div class="border1">
    @if(isset($results))
        @foreach($rooms as $room)
            <a href="#">$room->roomid</a>
        @endforeach
    @endif
</div>
```

Any and all help would be appreciated. Thank you

**UPDATE**
I forgot to clarify that, I got the error 'undefined variable $rooms' BEFORE I used an if condition to check if $errors was set. After I used if(isset($errors)) I didnt get the error anymore but the information I wanted to show up didn't show up

**UPDATE 2**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Dashboard</title>

<style>
    h1{
        text-align: center;
    }

    .border1{
        border: dotted;
        border-color: red;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 20px;
    }

    .ulerror{
        text-align: center;
        color: red;
    }

    .flash-message{
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: bolder;
        color: lawngreen;
    }

    ul li{
        font-family: "Lucida Console";
        font-size: 24px;
        list-style: none;
        padding: 10px;
    }

    a{
        padding: 8px;
    }
</style>

</head>
<body>

<h1>Dashboard</h1>

<div class="border1">

    @if(isset($rooms))
        {{--{{ dd(isset($rooms)) }}--}}
        @foreach($rooms as $room)
            <a href="#">{{ $room->roomid }}</a>
        @endforeach
    @endif
    {{--<a href="{{ route('roomdetails', ['id' => '1', 'status' => 'free'])        }}">1</a> IGNORE THIS--}}

</div>

<br><br><br>

<div class="border1">
    <b>Insert a new Room</b>
    <br><br>
    <form action="{{ route('viewroom') }}" method="POST">
        Please Insert The New Room Number<br>
        <input type="text" name="roomid"/>
        <button type="submit">Add New Room</button>
        <input type="hidden" value="{{ Session::token() }}" name="_token"/>
    </form>
</div>

<div class="flash-message">
    @foreach (['danger', 'warning', 'success', 'info'] as $msg)
        @if(Session::has('alert-' . $msg))

            <p class="alert alert-{{ $msg }}">{{ Session::get('alert-' .  $msg) }} <a href="{{ route('backhome') }}" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a></p>
        @endif
    @endforeach
</div> {{--flash message--}}

@if(count($errors) > 0)
    <div class="ulerror">
        <ul>
            @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                {{ $error }}
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div> {{--error handling--}}
@endif
```

Comment: What does `$rooms = InsertRoom::all(); dd($rooms);` show?

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin Basically I want to retrieve all the rows from the insert_rooms table and store it in the object $rooms. Then the variable $rooms is passed into the view and by using '$room->roomid' I try to obtain only the room id's which I want to display. Hope I was clear

Comment: I see this. ) To be able to help you, I need to debug it with you. Please use code from my previous comment and tell me the output.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin Sorry, my bad.. I thought you were asking what the code does. When I entered dd($rooms), I got the following output: Collection {#207 ▼
  #items: array:13 [▶]
}

Comment: Ok, now remove dd and add this into the view (before foreach): `{{ dd(isset($rooms)) }}`

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin I get a value returned as 'true'

Comment: So, variable is passed into the view. Do you use debugbar? If yes make sure that `dashboar.blade.php` is used. Also, update your question with full content of `dashboard` view please.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin No I do not use debugbar.. Should I? I will update my question with the full dashboard.blade.php code

Comment: @user3536523: Is your problem solved or not? You have just made a typo error as shown in answer. Are you still facing error?

Comment: @RaviHirani Sorry. I did not see the answer you posted. I am using mobile and it did not scroll down. And even after I changed $results to $rooms, I still didnt get the output I was looking for

Comment: @user3536523, try `{{ dd($rooms->count()) }}` before foreach. What does it show?

Comment: @user3536523: if there is a key named 'roomid' in $room object and if it has value  then it will show in the output otherwise it will display as blank without an error.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin It worked now! Thank you very much for all your help. What do you think was the problem?

Comment: @RaviHirani Yes, there is an id named roomid but the results were not showing. But now it is after I used {{ dd($rooms->count()) }}. Thank you for all your answers :)

Comment: @user3536523, `{{ dd($rooms->count) }}` is just should show something like this `int(13)` or `int(0)` or something similar. Do you see your view now or empty mage with some number?

Comment: $rooms->count() will give you count of records but how can it solve your problem?

Comment: To get boolean result we can consider if($rooms->count() > 0) is similar to if($rooms) is similar to if(isset($rooms)) is similar to if(!empty($rooms))

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin This is what i see now. Sorry I had to use an image hosting site: http://s32.postimg.org/tx3yi66vo/dashboard.jpg

Comment: @RaviHirani This is what i see now in my view http://s32.postimg.org/tx3yi66vo/dashboard.jpg

Comment: `dd` directive should stop execution and you would just see a number. So, I guess Laravel uses some other view. Or you've put `dd` into another view. Please doublecheck this.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin Those numbers on the top are what I wanted

Comment: @user3536523: It seems that your problem is resolved.

Comment: @user3536523, yes, but you still didn't fix that and you will get another problems soon, because you're editing one view but see abother one.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin As shown in the code in my question (in update 2), I have entered the dd into the dashboard.blade.php

Comment: @user3536523, look, if you did put `{{ dd` clause in this view, Laravel would **never** show you your view. It would show you just a blank page with some number. So, it's something wrong with your routes or views, if you'll leave it now as is, you will get another problem shortly. You're editing one view, but Laravel shows you something else.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin Yeah I get what you mean... Let me just recheck everything. Give me 5 minutes

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin Wow... I feel so stupid.... The     {{ dd }} was actually commented out which was why I got the output I wanted. Basically, all I needed was to surround my $room->roomid with {{ }} like Ravi Hirani and Shalu Singhal  said.... I feel bad for wasting your time :/

Answer (score 2):

You should try

```
<div class="border1">
@if(isset($rooms))
    @foreach($rooms as $room)
        <a href="#">{{$room->roomid}}</a>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

Comment: Well... It works now. I had to surround the $room->roomid with the double curly brackets... I feel so stupid for forgetting that. Thanks a lot for the help

Answer (score 0):

**Typo Error**: rooms instead of results. You haven't passed any variable named 'results' from your controller to view.

You just need to check if result object(rooms) is set or not. You can use any of below to do this.

All will return boolean result true or false.

```
@if($rooms)
    @foreach($rooms as $room)
        <a href="#">{{$room->roomid}}</a>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

OR

```
@if(!empty($rooms))
    @foreach($rooms as $room)
        <a href="#">{{$room->roomid}}</a>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

OR

```
@if(isset($rooms))
    @foreach($rooms as $room)
        <a href="#">{{$room->roomid}}</a>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing this: 
     return view('dashboard', ['rooms' => $rooms]);

Just print out all your rooms in your get view function. And then in your insertRooms function do a: 
    return redirect()->back();

Instead then your get view will automatically print out the new values because of a page refresh :-)

And please start using the compact method to return variables to your views, i has been best practice sine laravel 5.1 :-)

Also i would advice you to watch some videos on nameing conventions. Best of luck!

Comment: Thank you for your help! Is there a reason that compact method is used to return variables? Also, should I downgrade to Laravel 5.1? When reading about Laravel, I heard something about Laravel 5.2 will soon become obsolete, but I dont understand that because shouldn't Laravel 5.1 become obsolete before 5.2?

Comment: To my knowledge and my own experience it's mainly due to readability through out the code. I have just upgraded a project to 5.2 so i hope not :D i havent heard anything about it :-) if this solved your answer please accept it thanks!